# React middleware issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am migrating React app from React 16 to React 18 using Vite. I have an issue with routing and middleware, my index looks like that

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, cr  } from "react-router-dom";
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import globalStore from './reducers';
import sagas from './sagas';
import './i18n';
import './globalStyles.css';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), sagaMiddleware)];

const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    typeof window === 'object' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
        ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
                shouldHotReload: false,
                trace: true,
                traceLimit: 25,
          })
        : compose;

const store = createStore(globalStore(history), composeEnhancers(...enhancers));

sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <App history={history} />
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I'm getting error:

> typeerror: middleware is not a function

Comment: It seems like you're missing the import for `routerMiddleware` in your code. You need to import `routerMiddleware` from `react-router-redux`

Comment: *Other than* `ReactDOM.createRoot` nothing in your post is relevant to React 18. Redux `createStore` is deprecated and has been for a while now. *What* ***specific*** versions of Redux and React-Router-DOM (*looks like v5 something*) are you working with here? Your imports appear to be incomplete. What is `routerMiddleware`? Please [edit] to ensure you've provided a complete [mcve], the complete error message(s) and any accompanying error stacktrace(s).